# How can I delete multiple record by single checkbox in ASP.net Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to delete several records but Why this code doesn't work, When I trace the code the view doesn't return any value to the controller, what is the reason

This is Controller

```
public IActionResult DeleteAll(IEnumerable<SubCategoryViewModel> model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }

    List<SubCategory> subCategoriesWillBeDeleted = new List<SubCategory>();

    foreach (var subCategoriesVM in model)
    {
        if (subCategoriesVM.SubCategoryCheckBox.Selected)
        {
           subCategoriesWillBeDeleted.Add(_db.SubCategories.Find(subCategoriesVM.SubCategory.Id));
        }
    }

    _db.SubCategories.RemoveRange(subCategoriesWillBeDeleted);
    _db.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}
```

And this is View

```
@model IEnumerable<SubCategoryViewModel>

<form asp-action="DeleteAll" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(e => e.SubCategory.Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="allcheck" id="selectAll" /> Select All
            </th>
        </tr>
    @foreach (var subCategoryVM in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(e => subCategoryVM.SubCategory.Name)
             </td>
             <td>
                 <input type="hidden" asp-for="@subCategoryVM.SubCategoryCheckBox.Value" />
                 <input asp-for="@subCategoryVM.SubCategoryCheckBox.Selected" />
                 <input type="hidden" asp-for="@subCategoryVM.SubCategory.Id" />
             </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td></td>
             <td>
                 <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Delete" />
             </td>
         </tr>
     </form>     @section Scripts {
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#selectAll").click(function () {
            $("input[type=checkbox]").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
        });
        $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function () {
            if (!$(this).prop("checked")) {
                $("#selectAll").prop("checked", false);
            }
        });
    });
</script>}
```

And this SubCategoryViewModel class

```
public class SubCategoryViewModel
{
    public SubCategory SubCategory { get; set; }
    public SelectListItem SubCategoryCheckBox { get; set; }
}
```

Please help me, When I trace the code the view doesn't return any value to the controller

And if anyone has a more efficient solution than this, please help me out

Comment: You've forgotten to `[Bind]` the model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could refer the following sample code:

1. Create a ViewModel to display records:

```
    public class SubCategoryViewModel
          {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int Id { get; set; }
           
            public SelectListItem SubCategoryCheckBox { get; set; }
          }
```

2. Create a Model:

```
public class SubCategory
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
 
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
       
    }
```

3. In the Controller, add the following code:

```
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            List<SubCategoryViewModel> vm = new List<SubCategoryViewModel>();
            var items = _context.SubCategory.ToList();
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                vm.Add(new SubCategoryViewModel
                {
                    Id = item.Id,
                    Name = item.Name,
                  
                });
            }
 
 
            return View(vm);
        }
 
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult DeleteAll(List<SubCategoryViewModel> model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
 
            List<SubCategory> subCategoriesWillBeDeleted = new List<SubCategory>();
 
            foreach (var item in model)
            {
                if (item.SubCategoryCheckBox.Selected)
                {
                    var selectedEmployee = _context.SubCategory.Find(item.Id);
 
 
                    subCategoriesWillBeDeleted.Add(selectedEmployee);
                }
            }
            _context.SubCategory.RemoveRange(subCategoriesWillBeDeleted);
            _context.SaveChanges();
 
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
```

4.Then, in the View page (Index .cshtml), using the following code to display the content:

```
@model IList<mvcdelete2.ViewModel.SubCategoryViewModel>
 
 
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}
 
<h1>Index</h1>
 
<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<form asp-action="DeleteAll" method="post">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
 
                <th>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="allcheck" id="selectAll" /> Select All
                </th>
                <th>
                    Name
                </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
            {
                <tr>
 
                    <td>
                        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[i].SubCategoryCheckBox.Value" />
                        <input asp-for="@Model[i].SubCategoryCheckBox.Selected" />
                        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[i].Id" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label asp-for="@Model[i].Name">@Model[i].Name</label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
 
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div>
        <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Delete" />
    </div>
</form>
@section Scripts {
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#selectAll").click(function () {
                $("input[type=checkbox]").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
            });
            $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function () {
                if (!$(this).prop("checked")) {
                    $("#selectAll").prop("checked", false);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

5.The structure as below:

[image]

6.The result as below:

[image]

[image]